# TclOO: how to add class configuration methods without polluting namespace

Tags: tcl

In the bigger code block below (2nd block), I defined the proc `oo::define::capability` pretty much as mentioned here:

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/TclOO+Tricks#mkup_code_42

I can see uses potentially for the Registry pattern and potential application to a TCL style modelled after SQLAlchemy Declarative Python interface:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#codecell0

A few things I don't like about this code:

a. I don't want the additional configuration command `capability` generally available.  Only on certain classes, potentially with differing behaviour for different groups of classes different command names.

b. I have this line placed within the method `register`, I'd prefer with the variable statement (or eval? - didn't work):

> if {![info exists _registry]} { set _registry {} }

c. I tried defining a metaclass to resolve a). but had no real success.  I think possibly I'm confusing methods with configuration commands?  Is what I want (metaclass adding configuration commands) actually possible?

```
::oo::class create ::demo::metaclass {
    superclass ::oo::class
    
    self method create {name args} {
        set inst [next $name {*}$args]
        # to ensure metaclass on method lookup?
        oo::define $inst superclass -append [self]
        return $inst
    }
    
    # on the class? how to use this?
    self method capability {args} {
        # implementation as below
    }
}
```

minimal registry implementation

```
# Tcl 8.5
package require TclOO
package require struct::set

namespace eval ::demo {}

# https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/TclOO+Tricks#mkup_code_16
::oo::object create ::demo::registry
::oo::objdefine ::demo::registry {
    variable _registry
    
    method query {args} {
        set LoL {}
        foreach {cap val} $args {
            lappend LoL [dict get $_registry $cap $val]
        }
        set candidates [::struct::set intersect {*}$LoL]
        return $candidates
    }
    method register {capability value cls} {
        if {![info exists _registry]} { set _registry {} }
        
        dict update _registry $capability dval {
            dict lappend dval $value $cls
        }
    }
    unexport destroy
}

proc oo::define::capability {args} {
    set cls [lindex [info level -1] 1]
    foreach {cap val} $args {
        ::demo::registry register $cap $val $cls
    }
}

# https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Extending+TclOO+with+metaclasses#mkup_code_10
oo::class create ::demo::ICapa {
    method connect {} {} ; # abstract
}

oo::class create ::demo::PayloadCapa {
    superclass ::demo::ICapa
    capability -type cargo -capacity 500kg
}

oo::class create ::demo::GroundCapa {
    superclass ::demo::ICapa
    capability -type cart -rating 20A
}

# test
::demo::registry query -type cargo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, this is something that you'll need to wait for Tcl 8.7 for. *In 8.6 and before, the capability is absent.* A workaround is possible as described below, but it is definitely a workaround.

## The Proper Solution

In 8.7 (currently hovering on the edge of first beta), you'll be able to use `definitionnamespace` in a metaclass to specify which namespace to use for handling definition scripts for the classes that are instances of that metaclass. (You'll be able to also use it to adjust the definitions for instances.) This is used by the `oo::configurable` metaclass to add `property` definitions.

Note that definition commands are necessarily commands, and you probably ought to add in most standard definitions.

Here's the abbreviated version of how your example would become:

```
# The namespace containing/resolving the commands for processing definitions
namespace eval ::MyCapabilityDefinition {
    # Add standard definition commands as a group
    namespace path ::oo::define

    # New definition command
    proc capability {args} {
        # In 8.7, this is how you get the class being defined.
        # It NEEDS the uplevel; it looks at hidden state in the stack frame.
        set cls [uplevel 1 self]
        # However you want to implement it...
        foreach {cap val} $args {
            ::demo::registry register $cap $val $cls
        }
    }
}

# This makes a metaclass, and sets it to make classes that can use capability
oo::class create capabilityClass {
     superclass oo::class
     definitionnamespace -class ::MyCapabilityDefinition
}

# This is how to update one example class
capabilityClass create ::demo::PayloadCapa {   # Make with metaclass
    superclass ::demo::ICapa;                  # Ordinary superclass
    capability -type cargo -capacity 500kg;    # The extra definition
}
```

If you're doing things that look like properties (e.g., with a `configure` method) then you might be better off with the fuller version baked into `oo::configurable`.

## The Hacky Workaround

If you haven't got 8.7 yet, you could try using `namespace path` to add a profile of definitions temporarily to `oo::define`.

```
namespace eval ::MyCapabilityDefinition {
    proc capability {args} {
        set cls [lindex [info level -1] 1]; # The old way
        foreach {cap val} $args {
            ::demo::registry register $cap $val $cls
        }
    }
}

oo::class create capabilityClass {
     superclass oo::class
     self method create {className {definitionScript ""}} {
         namespace eval ::oo::define {::namespace path ::MyCapabilityDefinition}
         try {
             return [next $className $definitionScript]
         } finally {
             namespace eval ::oo::define {::namespace path {}}
         }
     }
}

capabilityClass create ::demo::PayloadCapa {
    superclass ::demo::ICapa
    capability -type cargo -capacity 500kg
}
```

The complication here is that you'll have to do that temporary changing of the path for each time you call `oo::define` on that class, but at least the path of the `oo::define` namespace is empty by default.

Comment: The advantage of the `definitionnamespace` stuff is that it is a baked-in mechanism; once you set it, you don't need to remember the details elsewhere.

Comment: is there anyway to improve my point b).?

Comment: I'm not sure there is, if you don't have a constructor in that class to put things into a known initial state. `info exists` is pretty efficient in 8.6 onwards.